# PySpark MLlib: AssertionError: Classifier doesn't extend from HasRawPredictionCol

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, svm, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am a newbie in Spark . I want to use multiclass classification for SVM in PySpark MLlib. I installed Spark 2.3.0 on Windows.

But I searched and found that SVM is implemented for binary classification only in Spark , so we have to use one-vs-all strategy. It gave me an error when I tried to use one-vs-all with SVM . I searched for the error but do not find a solution for it.

I used the code of one-vs-all from this link
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-classification-regression.html#one-vs-rest-classifier-aka-one-vs-all

here is my code :

```python
        from pyspark.mllib.classification import SVMWithSGD , SVMModel
        from pyspark.ml.classification import OneVsRest
        # instantiate the One Vs Rest Classifier.
        svm_model = SVMWithSGD()
        ovr = OneVsRest(classifier=svm_model)
        # train the multiclass model.
        ovrModel = ovr.fit(rdd_train)
        # score the model on test data.
        predictions = ovrModel.transform(rdd_test)
```

The error is in the line "ovr.fit(rdd_train)". Here is the error

```python
  File "D:/Mycode-newtrials - Copy/stance_detection -norelieff-lgbm - randomizedsearch - modified - spark.py", line 1460, in computescores
ovrModel = ovr.fit(rdd_train)
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\base.py", line 132, in fit
return self._fit(dataset)
  File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\classification.py", line 1758, in _fit
"Classifier %s doesn't extend from HasRawPredictionCol." % type(classifier)
 AssertionError: Classifier <class 'pyspark.mllib.classification.SVMWithSGD'> doesn't extend from HasRawPredictionCol.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because you are trying to use a model from Spark ML (`OneVsRest`) with a base binary classifier from Spark MLlib (`SVMWithSGD`).

[Spark MLlib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/mllib-guide.html) (the old, RDD-based API) and [Spark ML](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-guide.html) (the new, dataframe-based API) are not only different libraries, but they are also **incompatible**: you cannot mix models between them (looking closer at the examples, you'll see that they import the base classifier from `pyspark.ml`, and not from `pyspark.mllib`, as you are trying to do here).

Unfortunately, as at the time of writing (Spark 2.3) Spark ML does not include  SVMs, you cannot currently use the algorithm as a base classifier with `OneVsRest`...